# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: ValidationBase is not defined

Tags: knockout.js, oracle-jet

I am trying to run this example : https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=listView&demo=filterSortListView

I downloaded JET-Template-Web-NavBar and in dashboard.html and js replaced code given in example but it throws error saying

```
dashboard.js:73 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: ValidationBase is not defined
    at new DashboardViewModel (dashboard.js:73)
```

js file

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout','appController','ojs/ojmodel',   'ojs/ojvalidation-base', 'ojs/ojknockout', 
    'ojs/ojlistview', 'ojs/ojgauge', 'ojs/ojbutton', 'ojs/ojcheckboxset', 'ojs/ojselectcombobox', 'ojs/ojpagingcontrol'],
 function( oj,ko,  data ,  app ,  Model) {


    function DashboardViewModel() {
      var self = this;
```

rest is complete example copy paste and did not make any change to default main.js that comes with application. All modules seems available (all are 200 ok on debugger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the modules as the correct parameters to your function.

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout','appController','ojs/ojmodel',   'ojs/ojvalidation-base', 'ojs/ojknockout', 
    'ojs/ojlistview', 'ojs/ojgauge', 'ojs/ojbutton', 'ojs/ojcheckboxset', 'ojs/ojselectcombobox', 'ojs/ojpagingcontrol'],
 function(oj, ko, app, Model, ValidationBase) {


    function DashboardViewModel() {
      var self = this;
```